# Making available an iis webserver over a local network

Tags: iis, web-server

I'm trying to host a javascript display from one computer and have it be displayed on multiple computers on the local network.

So far I have my windows iis installed and can access http://localhost. Now, how do I get that url available to the other computers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have users access

```
http://192.168.0.1(or whatever your server's IP is)
```

or

```
http://IIS_Server_Name
```

Because the request comes in on port 80, IIS will respond and they will get whatever content your IIS server is hosting.

Alternatively, as Jeff said, set up  a CNAME that forwards to that host. i.e. MyWebSite > FQDN_of_IIS_Server, then have users access

```
http://MyWebSite.
```

Comment: wicked im connecting, however im getting a server error:401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

Comment: ah. I went into IIS manager and enabled anonymous authorization.

Answer (score 0):

The other machines from within your network may be able to access the web server either by its IP address or possibly its Netbios (machine) name.

Comment: so it's just the computer's ip? http:/192.etc.? or does IIS create an ip?

Comment: It looks like you have it answered.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Active Directory as your DNS then ask your Network team to create a DNS Alias (CNAME) that points to your computers name.